# Reduction of AUC if add more variables

Tags: logistic, auc

I have created a logistic regression with one predictor and the AUC is 0.85. When I add one more predictor the AUC is reduced. How is that possible? Shouldn't it always increase or stay the same as R squared? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. This is very vague. Could you add a lot more specific information?

Comment: Are you evaluating the in-sample AUC or the out-of-sample AUC?
For the latter, this is a classic case of the bias-variance tradeoff. More variables => less bias, but more variance. So the AUC might decrease because you do not have enough training data.

Comment: Hello, I am evaluating in the Aout of sample AUC (I use cross validation)